# getting src, width, height and alt of image (outerhtml) basically, mapping to an array

Tags: jquery

How would I get these values for example with these images and map them to an array.

```
<img height="307" width="256" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6a/MystCover.png" alt="MystCover.png">

<img height="135" width="220" class="thumbimage" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d0/Myst-library_and_ship.jpg/220px-Myst-library_and_ship.jpg" alt="">
```

I currently use this code just to test getting the src and it works well, but I need to get something like the "outerHTML" or .

```
   var images = $('img:area(10000)').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('src');
}).get();
```

Comment: didn't clear by what you mean by outerHTML ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this to get all those attributes:

```
var imageArray = $('img:area(10000)').map(function(){
    return {
        src: $(this).attr('src'),
        width: $(this).attr('width'),
        height: $(this).attr('height'),
        alt: $(this).attr('alt'),
        html: $(this).html()
    };
});
```

Comment: I found a way to get the outerHTML of the images. but this works also :)